# How to specify correct path for a media in assets for PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, media, assets

I am playing a audio using PhoneGap

```
    var media = new Media("/android_asset/book/snd/kolobok_ua.mp3", onMediaSuccess, onMediaError);

    if (seek){
        media.seekTo(seek);
    }
    media.play();
```

As you can see I am using "android_asset" here and it will not work for iphone.

**What is the best practice for specifying path for resources in assets?**

Comment: Are you needing to keep these files outside of the www folder?

Comment: No, I want to have more universal path for android and ios, but usage "/android_asset/..." seems not universal

Comment: If you have the file in the www folder, it's easy to reference in iOS. Then all you need is a small conditional to add Android's "/android/asset/www/" before iOS's "/book/snd/kolobok_ua.mp3"